# Find next td class and add class to current td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Hi I want to find the next **td** class and based on that i have to add a class to the current **td**.

I have a table like

```
<table>
 <tr>  
  <td class="parent-test-cls next-parent-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span> </div></td>
  <td class="parent-test-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
  <td class="parent-test1-cls next-parent-test1-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
  <td class="parent-test1-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
  <td class="parent-test-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What i have tried is

```
var $this_elt = elt.parent().next('td');
    if($this_elt.hasClass('parent-test-cls')){

        elt.parent().addClass('next-test-cls');

    }else if($this_elt.hasClass('parent-test1-cls')){

        elt.parent().addClass('next-test1-cls');

    }
```

But I'm not able add the class, where I'm wrong?

Comment: what is `elt`? And show your markup.

Comment: just a variable

Comment: add the markup and elt variable value.

Comment: you should add complete code snippet and all variables that are used to troubleshoot the problem here.

Comment: You are adding the class to the row not the `<td>` like you said you wanted to do. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Still, what is `elt`?

Comment: @user3668438 I think you are want something like https://jsfiddle.net/8rtyhydj/

Comment: elt is a div within td

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/mumodin/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

What I have understand by your question is that if you select a div and it parent's next have 'parent-test-cls' then selected div's parent will be added with a class 'next-test-cls'. I hope the following will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <style media="screen">
      .parent-test-cls {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .next-parent-cls {
        color: purple;
      }
      .parent-test1-cls {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 25px;
      }
      .next-parent-test1-cls {
        color: orange;
      }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="parent-test-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span> </div></td>
    <td class="parent-test-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
    <td class="parent-test1-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
    <td class="parent-test1-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
    <td class="parent-test-cls"><div><span> Test 1 </span></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').on('click', function() {
          if ($(this).parent().next().hasClass('parent-test1-cls')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('next-parent-test1-cls');
          }
          if ($(this).parent().next().hasClass('parent-test-cls')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('next-parent-cls');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>
```